# Footer of bootstrap modal covers timepicker dropdown menu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to include [this timepicker for bootstrap](http://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/) into a modal. However the footer of the modal covers the dropdown menu for the timepicker.

The z-index for the modal is 1000 and although I set the z-index of the dropdown menu of the timepicker to a higher value, but this didn't helped at all. I am using a datepicker as well, whose dropdown menu has a z-index of 1060 which is enough to be displayed above the modal footer.

Has anyone an idea, why the datepicker is working as it should but the timepicker isn't although I set their z-index to the same value?

Cheers,

metalhamster

---

**Edit:**

Computed style of timepicker dropdown menu.

[image: computed style of timepicker dropdown menu]

I have no idea why the z-index is only 1000, although I have:

```css
.bootstrap-timepicker {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1100 !important;
}
```

But even changing this to 1100 didn't solve my problem.

Comment: You're probably going to need to show your css/html code in order for anyone to help.

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue in a jsfiddle, in order to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
.modal-body {
  overflow-y:visible;
}
```

I had the same problem and read it from another answer on stack overflow :D